# Autologin, X Session, and Single Application (Oh My!)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

We have a very timid server whose only purpose *was* to run Apache and Nagios for asset monitoring. We are moving it center stage to drive a monitor for a 24/7 display of one of the Nagios screens in our IT room.

Due to the limited hardware resources of the machine, I want to install as little as possible to get this functionality. This means no window manager for sure. At present the machine boots up to a CLI login. I would like to change that to do the following:

1. Auto login to a specified user account
2. Launch an X session
3. Run `google-chrome --kiosk http://localhost/thepage/`

There are a lot of instructions on how to achieve this on older versions of Ubuntu but with 10.04 and 10.10 the locations and method of startup has changed significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

err. remove XDM/GDM completely and launch:

```
/bin/bash -c "su username -c startx"
```

edit /home/username/.xinitrc:
    google-chrome --kiosk http://localhost/thepage/

Chrome doesn't goes background; so once chrome is dead, X would stop.

Comment: I need the autologin to be on boot which is that part that's giving me the most trouble. From what I gather, I need something in `/etc/init.d/` and then I symlink to it from `/etc/rc2.d/`.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto

Comment: I will look for better Gentoo's /etc/conf.d/local.start alternative, don't know Ubuntu this good.